# Xamarin XAML to C# Data Trigger

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, maui

In reference to this question below I have XAML working, but am struggling with converting to C#

[Xamarin / MAUI XAML to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404330/xamarin-maui-xaml-to-c-sharp)

Here is my attempt that isn't working and I'm not sure why... My goal is when `LayoutState.Success` it updated via `VenuePageViewModel`, `VenueSuccessContentView` should display inside the `cvWrap` `ContentView` on the Page.

```
public partial class VenuePageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private LayoutState layoutState = LayoutState.Loading;

    public VenuePageViewModel()
    {
        LayoutState = LayoutState.Success;
    }
}

public class VenueSuccessContentView : ContentView
{
    public VenueSuccessContentView()
    {
        Content = new Label() { Text = "hello world", TextColor = Colors.Red };
    }
}

public class MainPageCS : ContentPage
{
    public MainPageCS()
    {
        BindingContext = new VenuePageViewModel();

        var venueSuccessCV = new VenueSuccessContentView();
        Resources.Add(nameof(LayoutState.Success), venueSuccessCV);

        var cvWrap = new ContentView();
        var cv = new ContentView();
        cvWrap.Content = cv;

        Content = cvWrap;

        var datatrigger = new DataTrigger(typeof(ContentView))
        {
            Binding = new Binding(source: RelativeBindingSource.TemplatedParent, path: nameof(VenuePageViewModel.LayoutState)),
            Value = LayoutState.Success,
            Setters = {
                new Setter { Property =  ContentView.ContentProperty, Value = venueSuccessCV },
            }
        };

        cvWrap.Triggers.Add(datatrigger);
    }
}
```

**Minimal Repo: https://github.com/aherrick/DataTriggerCSharpMaui**

Comment: Could you place `BindingContext = new VenuePageViewModel();` after `cvWrap.Triggers.Add(datatrigger);` ? The trigger should setup earlier than the property gets changed.

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT thanks for the thought. I tried that and doesn't seem to have worked. I've updated a GH minimal repo as well showing off the full functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding path is incorrect in DataTrigger .

Modify `Binding` property of DataTrigger as below .

```
Binding = new Binding( path: nameof(VenuePageViewModel.LayoutState))
```

Comment: i knew i was close! thanks :)